# Death Save Successes

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, character-death

When rolling for death saves, if you survive, you become stable on 0 hp. However, I had seen somewhere that if you end your turn on 0 hp, you must roll for death saves. So if I succeed in a death save (without rolling a nat 20), do I have to keep rolling death saves if I remain on 0 hp for another round of combat?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### You don't have to roll death saves once you are stable

The [death saving rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DeathSavingThrows) say you roll the death saves at the **start of your turn**, if you succeed **3 times** you become stable and so you **don't have to roll any more death saves**:

> Whenever you **start** your turn with 0 hit points, you must make a
> special saving throw, called a death saving throw
>
> ...
>
> On your **third** success, you become stable (see below)
>
> ...
>
> A stable creature **doesn't make death saving throws, even though it has 0 hit points**

Answer (score 3):

#### You only roll the death saved when *unstable*.

The rules for death saves state:

> A stable creature doesn’t make death saving throws

If you have rolled a natural 20, you are now stable and regain one hit point, and no more death saves must be rolled, unless something makes you unstable, like getting knocked out again by an attack.

Comment: Wait if you roll a nat 20 you aren't stable???

Comment: @Lamentix Typo, not -> now. Clarified my phrasing there.